# What's the difference between a function returning a Future.sync() and an async function without an await?

Tags: dart, async-await

I'm a seasoned developer but a Dart learner.

I compared a function returning a `Future.sync()` and an `async` function without an `await`, like this.

```
Future<void> measure(Future<int> Function() func) async {
  final watch = Stopwatch()..start();
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    sum += await func();
  }
  print('sum:$sum, dt:${watch.elapsed}');
}

void main() async {
  int i = 0;
  await measure(() => Future<int>.sync(
    () {
      i++;
      return i * 2;
    }
  ));
  i = 0;
  await measure(
    () async {
      i++;
      return i * 2;
    }
  );
}
```

The following is the result.

```
sum:100000010000000, dt:0:00:00.747827
sum:100000010000000, dt:0:00:00.874562
```

Are they equivalent? (I guess so.) If they are, why is the latter slower than the former? Where can I find the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Future.sync` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.3.0/dart-async/Future/Future.sync.html) runs its argument once, capturing any synchronous errors, and then returns the result as a future.
It's basically the same as:

```dart
Future<T> futureSync<T>(FutureOr<T> Function() fun) {
  try {
    var result = fun();
    if (result is Future<T>) return result;
    return Future<T>.value(result);
  } catch (e, s) {
    return Future<T>.error(e, s);
  }
}
```

where your `fun()` is, effectively, `=> ++i * 2;`.
(If you check the actual implementation, which is included in the DartDoc page, that's basically what it does, just with some more error handling to let zones intercept the syncronous error before it becomes an asynchronous error.)

In your case, that means it does `i++` and then returns a new `Future<int>.value(i * 2);`

The [`async` function](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await) with no `await` runs the code synchronously until it exits with a return or an error. If that return is with a future, then that future is awaited. (Yours is not a future.)
It's basically the same as:

```dart
Future<T> asyncFunc<T>(FutureOr<T> Function() fun) {
  Completer<T> $c = Completer<T>();
  try {
    var result = fun();
    // Async return:
    if (result is Future<T>) {
      result.then<void>($c.complete, onError: $c.completeError);
    } else {
      $c.complete(result);
    }
  } catch (e, s) {
    $c.completeError(e, s);
  }
  return $c.future;
}
```

In your case, the result is just an `int`, after doing `i++`, so it will always take the `else` branch. That means it's returning `$c.future` which is already completed with `i * 2`.

There should be no difference in the result values between the two approaches, both return a `Future<int>` that's already completed with the value of `++i * 2`.
And it would still be the same if your code returned a future or threw an error (at least if all compilers implemented `async` return of a future correctly).

The only possible difference will be timing.
You should not rely on specific timing of asynchronous code.
(And you shouldn't assume that an approach that is faster on one platform is necessarily also faster on another.)

It's very likely that the `async` version performs one extra delay, somewhere. Or delays a little later. Or runs a little more code to account for `async` return statements being quite complicated.
The difference here is small enough that I definitely woudldn't change what I did for performance reasons. Not unless I've identified this particular operation as a bottleneck.

(To optimize the `asyncFunc` slightly, as asked in below, one can instead do:

```dart
Future<T> asyncFunc<T>(FutureOr<T> Function() fun) {
  try {
    var result = fun();
    if (result is Future<T>) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return Future<T>.value(result);
    }
  } catch (e, s) {
    return Future<T>.error(e, s);
  }
}
```

The platform implementation deliberately avoids returning the original `Future`, to ensure that the type of function returned is always a platform future.)

Comment: @Irn In the `asyncFunc` example, would using `Completer<T>.sync()` instead of `Completer<T>()` be slightly faster  or would the behaviour be different altogether ?

Comment: Using a `Completer<T>.sync()` would be faster, and wrong. And being wrong faster isn't better. 
It's wrong because the `$c.completeError(e, s)` would then complete the future with an error, before anyone has had a chance to add an error handler. That error will immediately become an unhandled asynchronous error, and may crash your program.

It's possible to change `$c.complete(result)` to `return Future<T>.value(result);`, and `$c.completeError(e, s);` to `return Future<T>.error(e, s);`, and only use a (synchronous) completer for the delayed complete.